# A way to make hg mimic svn

Tags: svn, mercurial, emulation

I have an IDE with built-in support for `Subversion`, but none for `Mercurial`. What I want to try is to substitute the 'svn' command in the IDE settings with some wrapper script, which would interpret Subversion commands into Mercurial ones. The whole point of it is *not to bring up a Subversion repository*.

Are there some ways to make `hg` mimic `svn`? Maybe extensions?

(By the way, the IDE is `Altium Designer 10`, so a specific way to integrate with Mercurial would do too.)

Comment: There’s no such thing that I know of, you’ll have to write it yourself. But does the tool need a repository? Can’t you just use a stand-alone tool? It’s not ideal but not really a hassle either, for Mercurial I actually prefer to use TortoiseHg over Eclipse’s Mercurial plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time has passed, and what I decided to do is to follow Laurens Holst's suggestion and use TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion)

Comment: That one is for accessing SVN repos with Hg, using Mercurial syntax. What I need is, vice-versa, accessing Hg repos with SVN syntax.